# Accessing Javascript variables from JavaFX

Tags: javascript, google-maps, webview, javafx-2

I want to access javascript variables from JavaFX to control longitude and latitude variables  which are in googlemaps.html. x(long.) and y(lati.) variables will be defined as double and I will assign them some values inside JavaFX and these values will assign values to 2 variables ,named x2 and y2, inside Javascript.and then,a marker will be shown on googlemaps based on x2 and y2.
Why I want to control the values from JavaFX is x and y variables will be assinged from a text file.so I need to control them from Javafx...

Answer (score 2):

You can execute javascript using [`WebEngine.executeScript()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String%29) which will assing listeners to specified variables.

Those listeners can call JavaFX code, see `Calling back to Java from JavaScript` section of http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html for examples.